# PHP MySQL Search Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a code for MySQL search using two tables. But the results seems not correct

**Interface**
[image: Interface]

**"interpreters" Table Structure (This hold the info about interpreters)**[image]

**"terp_attributes" Table structure (This holds the attributes value ids available for terps)**

```
EX-  terp x has level 1 and level 2 certification 
Ex2- terp x can translate ASL and Spanish
```

[image]

**Sample data on above table**

[image]

I wrote a sql to get "Male or Female which has Certified (ta_attrvalid=1) or Level 1 Skills (ta_attrvalid=2)" and He also has "ASL" language (ta_attrvalid=6) attribute but it seems not working even i modified a lot. here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM 
interpreters ,terp_attributes 
WHERE (terp_gender='M' OR terp_gender='F') 
AND terp_agencyid=1 AND terp_id=ta_terpid 
AND ( ta_attrvalid=1 OR ta_attrvalid=2) 
AND ( ta_attrvalid=6)
```

Which should return "ta_terpid 3" data as the prediction but i cannot see any results

can anyone help me to resolve this query please,
Thanks a lot

Comment: I believe, you need to specify the table name in your WHERE clause. SELECT * FROM 
interpreters ,terp_attributes WHERE (interpreters.terp_gender='M' OR interpreters.terp_gender='F') 
AND interpreters.terp_agencyid=1 AND terp_attributes.terp_id=ta_terpid 
AND ( terp_attributes.ta_attrvalid=1 OR terp_attributes.ta_attrvalid=2) 
AND ( terp_attributes.ta_attrvalid=6)

Comment: `AND ( ta_attrvalid=1 OR ta_attrvalid=2) AND ( ta_attrvalid=6) ` - This is not possible.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel is there any other way to do this or shall i keep those attributes relationships in 3 separate tables, Thank You

Comment: Create same sample data and expected result. It's not clear, what you want. I guess you need some `EXISTS` subqueries.

Comment: "ta_terpid 3" literally match with this "Certified (ta_attrvalid=1) or Level 1 Skills (ta_attrvalid=2)" and has "ASL" language (ta_attrvalid=6) " but i don't know how to create a query for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to split your `attributes` table in `interpreters_skills`, `interpreters_languages` and `interpreters_locations`. However with your actual design you will need to join the table multiple times or use EXISTS subqueries like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM interpreters i
WHERE terp_gender IN ('M', 'F')
  AND terp_agencyid=1
  AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM terp_attributes a
      WHERE a.ta_terp_id = i.terp_id
        AND ta_attrvalid IN (1, 2)
  )
  AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM terp_attributes a
      WHERE a.ta_terp_id = i.terp_id
        AND ta_attrvalid IN (6)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,I'll check this

Comment: It works great, Thanks a lot for help :) Good luck...!